# The following define in C

Tags: c

```
// Register: BAUDCTL
  extern volatile unsigned char           BAUDCTL             @ 0x09B;
  #ifndef _LIB_BUILD
 asm("BAUDCTL equ 09Bh");
  #endif
```

what's @ sign? Is that mean defining a non-cacheable unsigned char at address 0x09B ?
then why it would need the asm function in assembly?

Answer (score 5):

It's a *compiler extension*, and not part of standard C. It places the variable on address `0x09b`. It's used only for a small subset of compilers for embedded platforms, where it's common to have variables for hardware registers.

---

Another common technique for this, on compilers that doesn't support `@` in their declarations (i.e. they are more standards compliant) is to use pointers. It would then look something like

```
volatile unsigned char *BAUDCTL = (unsigned char *) 0x09b;
```

The drawback of this is that the baud control register now takes up two places in memory, one for the actual hardware register and another for the pointer variable. Another drawback is that you have to use the pointer dereference operator to access the register.

Comment: I think Microchip has started leaving this behind by leaving it to the linker. I don't fully understand it, but I think they write linker scripts matched to header files, so you can use the names in your code and treat them as memory-mapped registers, but still write proper C.

Answer (score 2):

That's not standard C, it's some form of extension so what it means depends on the implementation. However, I'd say there was a very good chance you're correct and it's basically stating that the character is at address `0x9b`.

That's typically how memory-mapped I/O is done in embedded systems.

As to the need for the `asm` bit, again this is supposition (though well-educated): your `extern` may well define BAUDCTL for the **`C`** code but, if you want to use it within later **`asm`** blocks as well, it may need an assembler definition. It's possible that there's no easy way to get at the C definintions from within `asm` blocks.